# Magento Community: Product / Category Images do not upload

Tags: image, upload, magento, product

I have tried all the obvious:
 - chmod
 - php.ini
 - reinstalled magento

Anything else?

Comment: What's the error? In what function, in what library?

Comment: It would  be helpful to know exactly what is happening.  Are you getting an error (if so, what is it?)?  Are the upload buttons even working at all?  What happens?

As Sid Vel mentioned, it certainly could be a flash issue, however, I think newer versions have that resolved.  You could always try installing Flash 9 instead of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ages ago. Try check the version of Flash. Maybe there is something to do with the Flash Image uploader.

Is the image showing 100% and then stopping? This could possibly be a space issue. Check if you have enough space. You also need to set permissions to the media, upload directories after a move or upgrade.

Try the Magento Forums with the specific query. There have been issues with images in the past.